# How to get the MAX value in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

How to get the MAX value in every albumID(45, 12, 22, 8) in the following table?
I tried with this query.
But it returned me the first value, not max value.(3, 6, 5, 6)

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            contentnew
        WHERE
            genreID = 1
        ORDER BY
            albumID DESC,
            reg_count DESC
    ) AS newTB
GROUP BY
    albumID;
```

Look this

[image: table]

If I use the

[image]

Comment: What purpose does the outer `SELECT *` do? You should be able to do this as one `SELECT`.

Comment: Hint: `SELECT album_id, MAX(reg_count)`

Comment: Then can I get the rest of the values except max value?
e.g. : (6, 5, 9, 6, 1, 7, 3, 1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you group by, you can apply aggregate functions such as max on each group. In your example try:

```
SELECT albumID, max(reg_count) as max_count
FROM contentnew 
GROUP BY albumID
```

This will project each albumID with the max_count in the group. In the select statement you can only use aggregate functions. The reason why we are able to project (or print) albumID is because this is the column we grouped by.

Following comments:

```
SELECT *
FROM contentnew as c1
WHERE c1.reg_count < (
    SELECT max(c2.reg_count)
    FROM contentnew as c2
    WHERE c1.albumID = c2.albumID
    GROUP BY c2.albumID)
```

Comment: Then can I get the rest of the values except max value? 
e.g. : (6, 5, 9, 6, 1, 7, 3, 1)

Comment: To clarify: do you want to print out a table with the max removed from each group? Are you still trying to group after the max has been removed?

Comment: Thank you to response.  I don't want group anymore. I just want to print out a table with max removed from each group.  p.s: can we talk in skp? live:.cid.a7b12569f3452c15

Comment: No problem. Let's try a correlated subquery, I will edit my answer above to include the code.

Comment: Jin, I won't have time, but don't feel as though you owe me anything. Glad I've been able to help, best of luck on future coding!

Comment: How to get the max(reg_count)'s row?

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
select max(reg_count) from contentnew group by albumID
```

Comment: Then can I get the rest of the values except max value? 
e.g. : (6, 5, 9, 6, 1, 7, 3, 1)

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there, one thing that might be helpful is to use row_number() function, if you want every column from the table.

```
with contentnew_test
as
(
select row_number() over (partition by albumId order by reg_count desc) row
,* from 
contentnew
)
select * from contentnew_test where row = 1 order by reg_count desc;
```

I used this as a reference as not sure about the syntax
https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/mysql-row_number-function/

Subquery will give you a result set something like this:

```
row albumId reg_count  ...
1   1        8         ...
2   1        7         ...
3   1        3         ...
4   1        1         ...
1   2        22        ...
2   2        9         ...
3   2        6         ...
4   2        1...and so on.
```